# iTunes Match music gone missing

Tags: itunes-match

I have been an iTunes Match for several years, since shortly after they introduced the service.  Recently I noticed that entire albums were missing off my phone, or weirder still, that some albums would have two or three tracks present and the rest missing.

After checking that I did not have “Only Offline Music” selected, I did the obvious: I logged out of my Apple ID account and logged back in. A lot more music disappeared. Now roughly 90% of my music is missing.

Some artists are entirely present, some have taken huge hits, and a lot have exactly one song each.

I have also deauthorized my main computer (which has all my music) and reauthorized it in the hopes that would force a resync, but no such luck.

I should also mention that I never signed up for Apple Music, not even the free trial. I know there were some problems there, but that’s not the cause of my woes.

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out: in the Settings app, under Music, “iCloud Music Library” was somehow disabled. Problem solved!